# type without identifier parameter in a static void function

Tags: c++, syntax

I saw code below the other day, (I have sanitized it because it was not open source/public) but dont understand how the type without identifier does anything/is used. I cannot find anything that clearly describes what is happening here seems like a pre-declaration thing or a prototyping thing but this was the actual function definition, can anyone explain, sorry if it is a newbie question.

```
static void myfunction(int /*comment*/)
{
    // code here, loop that waits for a pid to exit
}
```

Comment: It's just a parameter without a name. So yes, it cannot be actually used in the function. Sometimes people do this to match the function prototype (maybe they override a virtual function which hast this parameter)

Comment: This is mentioned in the C++ standard at `[dcl.fct.def.general]` paragraph 6: "[*Note.* Unused parameters need not be named.]"  It was news to me too.  C doesn't allow this, incidentally; in C parameters must have names whether you use them or not.

Answer (score 2):

The argument isn't used in the function, and to avoid possible warnings about that one could omit the argument variable name.

Whatever value is passed when calling the function is simply ignored.

---

Since the C++17 standard you can also use the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute to tell that an argument might not be used inside the function:

```
static void myfunction([[maybe_unused]] int argument)
{
    // ...
}
```

This attribute can also be used for other variables, not only arguments, as well as for whole functions.

Answer (score 0):

An unnamed int could be used as a placeholder for differentiating identical function signatures, a classical example could be to overload the post-increment and pre-increment operator:

```
//Define prefix increment operator
Point& Point::operator++()
{
   _x++;
   _y++;
   return *this;
}

// Define postfix increment operator.
Point Point::operator++(int)
{
   Point temp = *this;
   ++*this;
   return temp;
}
```